# Passing session variables to other pages in cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm trying to pass session variables in cakephp. This is how I tried:

LoginController.php:-

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Controller;
    session_start ();
    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

    class LoginController extends AppController
    {
        public function loginentry(){
                    $loginid = $this->request->data('LoginID');
                    $password = $this->request->data('Password');

                    $login = TableRegistry::get('login');
                    $result = $login->loginuser($loginid, $password);
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    //extract($result);
                    //echo "\$a = memberid; \$b = membertype; \$c = roleid";

                    if($result == false){
                        $this->Flash->error(__("Incorrect Login"));
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION ["MemberID"] = $result[0]->memberid;
                        $_SESSION ["MemberType"] = $result[0]->membertype;
                        $_SESSION ["MemberName"] = $result[0]->membername;
                        $_SESSION ["RoleID"] = $result[0]->roleid;                      
                            //  $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Mom', 'action' => 'momlist']);
                        }
                    }
    }
```

MomController.php:-

class dtHelper {
    public $aaData;
}
class MomController extends AppController {

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize ();
}

    public function editor($id = NULL)
{
    $this->set('mid', $id);
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $momid = $this->request->data( 'MomID' );
        $momtitle = $this->request->data ( 'MomTitle' );
        $customerid = $this->request->data ( 'CustomerID' );
        $meetingheldon = $this->request->data ( 'MeetingHeldOn' );
        $session = $this->request->data ( 'Session' );
        $meetingstartedat = $this->request->data ( 'MeetingStartedAt' );
        $meetingendedat = $this->request->data ( 'MeetingEndedAt' );
        $participantsfromcustomerside = $this->request->data ( 'ParticipantsFromCustomerSide' );
        $staffid = implode(',', $this->request->data ( 'StaffID' ));
        $location = $this->request->data ( 'Location' );
        $Mom = TableRegistry::get ( 'Mom' );
        if(isset($id) && $id > 0){
            $result = $Mom->update ( $momid, $momtitle, $customerid, $meetingheldon, $session, $meetingstartedat, $meetingendedat, $participantsfromcustomerside, $staffid, $location);
        } else {
            $result = $Mom->create ( $momtitle, $customerid, $meetingheldon, $session, $meetingstartedat, $meetingendedat, $participantsfromcustomerside, $staffid, $location);
        }
        $message=$result['message'];
        if($result['webid']>0){
            $this->Flash->success($message);
            return $this->redirect ( [ 'Controller' => 'Mom','action' => 'momlist'] );
        }else{
            if(isset($id) && $id > 0)
            {
                $result = (object) array( 'momid'=>$momid,'momtitle'=>$momtitle,'customerid'=>$customerid,'meetingheldon'=>$meetingheldon,'session'=>$session,'meetingstartedat'=>$meetingstartedat,'meetingendedat'=>$meetingendedat,'participantsfromcustomerside'=>$participantsfromcustomerside,'staffid'=>$staffid,'location'=>$location);
                $this->set(array('row'=>$result,'mode'=>'Update'));
            }
            else{
                $result = (object) array( 'momtitle'=>$momtitle,'customerid'=>$customerid,'meetingheldon'=>$meetingheldon,'session'=>$session,'meetingstartedat'=>$meetingstartedat,'meetingendedat'=>$meetingendedat,'participantsfromcustomerside'=>$participantsfromcustomerside,'staffid'=>$staffid,'location'=>$location);
                $this->set(array('row'=>$result,'mode'=>'Save'));
            }
            $this->Flash->error($message);
        }
    } else {
        $mom = TableRegistry::get('Mom');
        $momlist = $mom->getlist();
        $this->set(array('momlist' => $momlist));

        $customer = TableRegistry::get('customer');
        $customerlist = $customer->getlist();
        $this->set(array('customerlist' => $customerlist));

        $project = TableRegistry::get('mom');
        $projectlist = $project->getprojectlist(1);
        $this->set(array('projectlist' => $projectlist));

        if(isset($id) && $id > 0)
        {           
            $mom=TableRegistry::get('mom');
            $result = $mom->getbyid($id);
            $this->set(array('row' => $result, 'mode' => 'Update'));
        }
        else{
            $this->set( array('mode'=>'Save'));
        }
    }
    $this->render ();
}
}
```

editor.ctp:-

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MomID" name="MomID" value="<?=isset($row->momid)?$row->momid:0 ?>">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Session" name="Session" value="<?= $_SESSION["memberid"]; ?>">
```

This is how, I tried to write the values to the session variables. I wanted to use these session variables in different pages. I've assigned the values to those variables to those `$_SESSION` variables, but I don't know how to read them in another page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing an undefined index `memberid`, it is supposed to be `MemberID`.

```
value="<?= $_SESSION["MemberID"]; ?>"
```

Comment: I get this error:Notice (8): Undefined index: memberid [APP/Template\mom\editor.ctp, line 4]">  if I don't include <?php session_start(); ?>, If I include that I get: Notice (8): A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() [APP/Template\mom\editor.ctp, line 1]

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I get the same error. Should I change something else??

Comment: Can you try this first: `print_r($_SESSION);` and show me the output?

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked. The problem was with a space between the `N` in SESSION and `[`. Now it's done. By the way, adding or removing the spaces will also play an important role in cakephp?

Comment: Ah that's why. No, the correct syntax should be without space between. :) Btw, you can mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: While this may solve the problem, accessing superglobals directly is _highly_ discouraged in CakePHP, this will only bring you in trouble, especially in the test environment. @duddosai

Answer (score 1):

Read CakePHP documentation

- **How to use session: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html**
- **How to use Authentication http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html**
- **Blog Tutorial - Authentication and Authorization: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html**

Comment: Salines: I have read that, but that's not the way I'm gonna do. I'm doing it in the way, I showed. How can I do with the above method?

Comment: Then you do not need any framework. CakePHP and other frameworks are built by experienced developers, who have realized that most of the code can be used in a simpler way, without repetition code (DRY) or write spaghetti code, the most important is that the code must be written in certain rules, so that future developers more easily perform the upgrade application. I hope you understand.